# Printing rich text with Boostrap, BR elements completely ignored by IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, xpages, xpages-extlib

When I print a document which contains rich text fields and has the bootstrap theme applied the `<br>` elements in the rich text are completely ignored when printing from IE. When printing from Chrome the `<br>` are respected.

Is this something specific to Bootstrap or specific with the Bootstrap implementation within XPages?

How can I explicit set a css rule for a print stylesheet that `<br>` elements are printed as they are displayed on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Stylesheet to the page header specifically for print. See this article as an example: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

You want to add media screen to the default style sheets to be sure. Eventually

```
br { display : block }
```

does the trick already. Keep in mind: IE is nowhere close to modern CSS.

Comment: that looks okey in the browser but then when printed the double br elements are printed as 1 element

Comment: AFAIK the print rendering engine isn’t the same as the browser rendering engine. Charge your customer double

Comment: I am a corporate developer so I charged nothing for re-branding the rich text fields when the fields are loaded: function rebrand2(){
 $( "<p class='rebranded'>&nbsp;</p>" ).replaceAll( "br" );
}

$(function() {
    rebrand2()
}